# Why is $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x=0$? Does $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \sqrt{x}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

If I remember right, $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ if

1. $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists
2. $f(a)$ exists
3. $f(a) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$

So $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \sqrt{x}$ exists? Thus $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \sin(\sqrt{x})$ [exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929450/prove-lim-x-to-0-sin-sqrtx-does-not-exist)?

Comment: In order to be completely safe, I think it is better to say it is continuous *from the right*. Some here though think that continuous may be enough as far as we refer to points within the domain of definition. I don't like that but it may be a matter of agreement.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ does not care about anything outside the domain of $f$ (except possibly $a$, which must be an adherent point, or even an accumulation point of the domain, depends on the used definition of the limit). If your $\sqrt{x}$ is only defined for $x \geqslant 0$, then $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \sqrt{x}$. If the domain also contains negative real numbers … it should take complex values, but still be continuous at $0$.

Comment: @DonAntonio So continuity definition depends on the textbook?

Comment: Well, as you can see Daniel takes the other agreement and not what I like, as I wrote. Anyway, it is always better and safer to look into the book.

Comment: Note that the definition of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ makes no reference to $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ or $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$. Those three concepts, while clearly similar, exist (almost) independently of one another.

Comment: My opinion is that continuity on a boundary needs to be checked -- and the double sided limit applies to values in the open interval of the your boundary values.

Answer (score 1):

You make a single mistake in your question: you forget to specify the domain of definition of $\sqrt \cdot$. You know that this is $[0, \infty)$, so "limit in $0$" here means, necessarily, "limit from the right" - simply because there is nothing to the left of $0$ in $[0, \infty)$.

If you prefer to be more pedantic, you could say that $[0, \infty)$ carries the subspace topology induced by the topology of $\Bbb R$: a subset $U \subseteq [0, \infty)$ is open (in the topology of $[0, \infty)$) if and only if there exist some open subset $V \subseteq \Bbb R$ (in the topology of $\Bbb R$) such that $U = V \cap [0, \infty)$. It is enough to notice now that all these open subsets $U$ are "truncated to the left of $0$".

Answer (score 0):

If we define $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ only for $x \geq 0$, then the function is *continuous on the right*; i.e., there the right-sided limit
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} f(x).
$$
As for the left-sided limit, it all depends on how $f(x)$ is defined for $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'll bite with the classic proof for the limit from the right, where the square root function has real value.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then taking $\delta=\epsilon^2$ we get
$$
|x|<\epsilon^2\Rightarrow |\sqrt{x}|<\epsilon
$$